# Is it possible to create a site using react js where I can show my assorted files like in share point?

Tags: reactjs

Possible Output similar to this

[image: Ideal Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but not with React alone (or any other front-end library/framework). Websites cannot be granted access to local filesystem; that would be too dangerous.

You can, however, build a backend that would make it possible to list and open files from your local machine, and then use this backend in your React application to display the UI.

Comment: Thank you on this sir. I thought it is possible with react alone. Would you be able to suggest some learning materials / video or anything that may help me to create this kind of application?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, as the other answer said, you need a backend to serve the files though.

I recommend using express js to build your backend, see their tutorials:

1. [hello world](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)
2. [serving static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)